# Wordpress GET theme mod, funcions.php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this in my functions.php :

```
function themename_customize_register($wp_customize){
//  =============================
    //  = Color Picker              =
    //  =============================
    $wp_customize->add_setting('themename_theme_options[link_color]', array(
        'default'           => '000',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'           => 'option',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
        'label'    => __('Link Color', 'themename'),
        'section'  => 'themename_color_scheme',
        'settings' => 'themename_theme_options[link_color]',
    )));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'themename_customize_register');

//ADD THE GET_THEME_MOD SCRIPT HERE? IT DOESNT SEEM TO WORK. ON THE OTHER HAND, ADDING IT INSIDE, DOES NOT WORK EITHER.
```

All I want to do, is add the default or chosen value to the header, so the CSS updates.
How do i get the Value?